# If the minimum Q value is decreasing and the maximum Q value increasing, is this a sign that dueling double DQN is diverging?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, q-learning, deep-rl, dqn, convergence

I'm training a dueling double DQN agent with prioritized replay buffer and notice that the min Q values are decreasing, while the max Q values are increasing.

Is this a sign that it is diverging?

Or should be just be looking at the mean Q value, which has a slight uptrend?

[image]

*<sup>1</sup> There are 2 different colored lines because the initial training (in orange) was stopped at around 1.3M time steps, and resumed (in blue) from a checkpoint at around 1.1M time steps*

*<sup>2</sup> Plots are from Tensorboard, visualizing data generated by Ray/RLlib*

*<sup>3</sup> Epsilon starts at 1.0 and anneals to 0.02 over 10000 time steps. The sudden increase in magnitude of Q-values appear to come after resuming from checkpoint, but might just be a coincidence.*

---

After training for more steps...

[image]